# A JTextPane that looks like a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, nimbus

Since we started on the wrong foot, I ask again, previous question deleted. Please check it out, the border of JTextPane IS NOT the same as the border of JTextArea, not by default:

So I need a JTextPane that looks exactly like a JTextArea.

I set the border of the JTextPane to new JTextArea().getBorder();. It looks like it should, however, focus isn't being drawn properly... How do I fix it?

I'm using Nimbus here, if it's any help...

THE SSCCE:

```
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;


public class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels())
    {
        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName()))
        {
            try
            {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e)

            {
                System.out.println("No Nimbus!");
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    JFrame a = new JFrame("Test");
    a.setSize(200, 400);
    a.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    a.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(a.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    JTextPane[] b = new JTextPane[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        b[i] = new JTextPane();
        b[i].setBorder(new JTextArea().getBorder());
        b[i].setText(Integer.toString(i));
        a.getContentPane().add(b[i]);
    }

    a.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

I've set the border to be the same one as on JTextArea, but the focus is not being painted or moved properly. If you comment out that line, there will be no border whatsoever.

Comment: *"I'm using Nimbus here, if it's any help..."*  Does the problem occur when *not* using Nimbus?  If so, including that code is a waste of space.  If it *works* in another PLAF, then Nimbus is vital to understanding the problem.

Comment: Testing out the code it seems if not using Nimbus then there is no border with and without the `setBorder()` call.

Comment: What I need to do is mess around with the code that paints the focus. I have to alter the some part of it to draw the focus properly, but I don't know which part, that's why I'm asking you... I'll look around the src.zip...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a Focus Listener that forces a repaint, then the strange behvaiour goes away.

Example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    final JTextPane b = new JTextPane();
    b.setBorder(new JTextArea().getBorder());
    b.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
            b.repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
            b.repaint();
        }

    });
    b.setText(Integer.toString(i));
    a.getContentPane().add(b);
}
```

This seems like a hack fix, but I am not sure why this is happening.